# Limit points of $\lbrace f(n) \rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In this paper [On the Limit Points of the Sequence $\sin n$](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2688681?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) the author proves that the limit points of this sequence are the real numbers in $[0,1]$.
My question is: Are there other functions $f$ such that $\lbrace f(n) \rbrace$ has $\mathbb{R}$ as set of limit points?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the remark! :)

Comment: There are many such results. For example, let $\alpha$ be irrational, and let $f(n)$ be the fractional part of $n\alpha$. Then the set of limit points of the set $\{f(n)\}$ is the set of all reals in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : But he asked for $\mathbb{R}$ not $[0,1]$ (hence it is much harder).  We can consider $f(n)$ an enumeration of the rationals, or of the rationals of the form $\pm \frac{a}{2^b}$. many other possibilities, but not so many "easily" definable.

Comment: @user1952009: One can get an explicit variant of the fractional part of $n\alpha$ that has all reals as limit points, though all non-negative reals is somewhat more pleasant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : will you use the [diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation) of $\alpha$ for that ?

Comment: @user1952009:  No, just a pairing function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : yes of course, $\tan( \pi  \alpha n)$

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:undergraduate-research] tag. It is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many such results. For example, let $\alpha$ be irrational, and let $f(n)$ be the fractional part of $n\alpha$. Then the set of limit points of the set $\{f(n)\}$ is the set of all reals in the interval $[0,1]$.

If we want to get all non-negative reals, we can modify the idea as follows. Any positive integer can be uniquely expressed as $2^{k}(2m-1)$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer and $m$ is a positive integer. Let $f(n)=k+(m\alpha)$, where $(m\alpha)$ is the fractional part of $m\alpha$. A not large modification will get us all reals as limit points.